Firebase credentials using dotenv file and getting this error ""undefined" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at Object.<anonymous>"?
I am getting this error when I am creating Firebase admin credentials using the dotenv file. I want to hide Firebase credentials and want to parse the private key JSON. Experts please have a look
Error
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\Helpers\database\Firebase\config.js:1:29)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (K:\Development\MindFuel\Backend\Helpers\database\Firebase\connectFirebase.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)

Node.js v20.11.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

DotEnv File
#Firebase
SERVICE_ACCOUNT='{
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\---------\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
"type":"service_account",
"project_id":"---" ,
"private_key_id": "-----",
"client_email": "------",
"client_id": "----",
"auth_uri": "--------",
"token_uri": "-------",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "-------",
"client_x509_cert_url": "-------",
"universe_domain": "--------"
 }'

Config.js
const serviceAccount = JSON.parse(process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT);

module.exports = serviceAccount;

ConnectFirebase.js
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require('./config');

const firebaseDb = () => {
    console.log(serviceAccount);
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        storageBucket: `gs://${process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`
    })

    console.log("firebase Connected");
};

module.exports = firebaseDb;

Any help will be appreciated :)
